# database must be an instance of database pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying this

```
username1 = "admin"
password = "password"
host = "localhost"

prefix = 'mongodb://' + username1 + ':'
suffix =  '@' + host + ':27017/'
connString =  prefix + urllib.quote(password) + suffix
db = MongoClient(connString)
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)//getting error at this line
```

And the error is **database must be an instance of database pymongo**.

I am following [this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/gridfs.html)

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: could you also show the imports?

Comment: You need to provide `database` to `GridFS` as shown in the example. Right now you `db` is a database connection. Use `db = MongoClient(connString).my_collection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The misunderstanding here is a result of misnomer.

The following creates a connection.

```
connection = MongoClient(connString)
```

To get a `pymongo.database` object you can readily make one on the fly by accessing an inexistent field on the connection instance or one for a database that already exists.

```
db = connection.roundhouse # where roundhouse is the name for my database
```